# Spark and scala: chain a function if

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I've been working on an ETL for Spark using Scala, in this ETL I want to add 3 arguments to respectively define `repartionBy`, `partitionBy`, `orderBy` to write my dataframe to storage.  However, those arguments need to be optional.

I really do not want to write a horrible `if...else` statement that would accept any combination of the 8 possibilities.
I have a function:

```
def writer(
  outputFormat: String,
  outputFile: String,
  outputMode: SaveMode,
  outputRepartionBy: String,
  outputParitionBy: String,
  outputOrderBy: String,
  dryRun: Boolean = false
)(df: DataFrame): Unit = {

        if (dryRun){
            df.show(500, false)
        }else{
            if (outputFormat == "parquet" || outputFormat == "orc" ) {
                df.write.format(outputFormat).mode(outputMode).save( outputFile )
            } else {
                df.write.format(outputFormat).save(outputFile)
            }
        }
    }
```

Would it be possible to do something like :

```
df.write
.if( outputRepartionBy != null ){ repartitionby( outputRepartionBy ) }
.format( outputFormat )
.mode(outputMode)
.save( outputFile )
```

Would it be the correct way to chain a function if a condition is meet and if not is there such a possibilities in scala/spark ?

Edit: I'm on Spark 2.3.1 with Scala 2.11.12

Comment: Which version of Spark are you using?

Comment: See my edit @kfkhalili

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have use [this blog post](http://cogita-et-visa.blogspot.com/2013/04/chain-call-style-functions-if-else.html) to achieve the logic I wanted, it look way nicer and it's very neat.

```
sealed class ConditionalApplicative[T] private (val value: T) { // if condition class wrapper
   class ElseApplicative(value: T, elseCondition: Boolean) extends ConditionalApplicative[T](value) {
   // else condition class wrapper extends ConditionalApplicative to avoid double wrapping 
   // in case: $if(condition1) { .. }. $if(condition2) { .. }
      def $else(f: T => T): T = if(elseCondition) f(value) else value
   }

   // if method for external scope condition
   def $if(condition: => Boolean)(f: T => T): ElseApplicative =
      if(condition) new ElseApplicative(f(value), false) 
      else new ElseApplicative(value, true)

   // if method for internal scope condition
   def $if(condition: T => Boolean) (f: T => T): ElseApplicative =
      if(condition(value)) new ElseApplicative(f(value), false) 
      else new ElseApplicative(value, true) 
}

object ConditionalApplicative { // Companion object for using ConditionalApplicative[T] generic
   implicit def lift2ConditionalApplicative[T](any: T): ConditionalApplicative[T] =
      new ConditionalApplicative(any)

   implicit def else2T[T](els: ConditionalApplicative[T]#ElseApplicative): T =
      els.value
}
```

by importing this in my method I can do thing like that :

```
 def writer(outputFormat: String, outputFile: String, outputMode: SaveMode, outputRepartionBy: String,outputParitionBy :String, outputOrderBy :String, dryRun: Boolean = false)(df: DataFrame): Unit = {
        import etl.tool.ConditionalApplicative._
        if (dryRun){
            df.show(500, false)
        }else{
            if (outputFormat == "parquet" | outputFormat == "orc" ) {
                df
                    .$if(outputOrderBy != null){
                        _.orderBy(col(outputOrderBy))
                    }.$if(outputRepartionBy != null){
                        _.repartition(col(outputRepartionBy))
                    }.write.format(outputFormat).mode(outputMode)
                    .$if(outputParitionBy != null){
                        _.partitionBy(outputParitionBy)
                    }.save( outputFile )

            } else {
                df.write.format(outputFormat).save(outputFile)
            }
        }
    }
```

The resulting code is speaking for itself. Though my understanding of the underlying logic is limited.

Comment: @Yuriy I've used your code hope you don't mind too much

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like

```
val temp=df.write.format(outputformat)
val writer =if ( outputRepartionBy != null )  temp.repartitionby(outputRepartitionBy)  else temp
writer.mode(outputMode).save(outputFile)
```

Comment: it was only an example, I should have add orderby and partitionby statement to my example, I understand what you mean. However I'm a bit disappointed by scala on this one, I would have bet something nicer existed